# Upload images to MongoDB after compressing and delete images from the Multer uploads directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, es6-promise, multer

I am very new to development related work. **PLEASE HELP**

I am trying to upload 10 images taken from user (implemented via MULTER) to the mongoDB database but, before final upload I want to compress the images using SHARP.

I tried doing this using callbacks. But FAILED.

This is what I want to do:

1. use MULTER to upload an array of 10 images to the `UPLOADS/IMAGES` directory.
2. FOR EACH file in the array use SHARP to compress the file and store the new compressed `.jpeg` file to `UPLOADS/COMPRESSED` directory.

THEN

3. use `fsPromises.readFile` to read the newly compressed image in the `UPLOADS/COMPRESSED` directory.

THEN

4. make an object :  `const toInsertImgData = { data: result, contentType: "image/jpeg"};`
   and push it in an array called `imgArray`. Here `result` is binary data read in the previous step.

THEN

5. use `fsPromises.unlink` to remove all files in `UPLOADS/IMAGES` and `UPLOADS/COMPRESSED`

THEN

6. Use the `imgArray` to make a document to save in the `posts` collection of the Database.

---

Right now every time the `imgArray` is empty when I want to use it at the end. I know that **PROMISES** or **AYSNC/AWAIT** can help. But I am not sure how to implement it.
Please help .

**THANKYOU IF YOU HAVE READ THIS FAR**

---

Here is my code:

```
const promises = [];
app.post("/compose/:id", upload.array("image", 10), (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const imgArray = [];
  const caption = req.body.caption;
  const now = new Date();

  
  req.files.forEach((file) => {
    const compressedImgPath =__dirname +"/public/uploads/compressed/" +now.getDate() +"-" +(now.getMonth() + 1) +"-" +now.getFullYear() +"-" +now.getTime() +".jpeg";
    sharp(file.path)
      .resize(640, 480)
      .jpeg({
        quality: 80,
        chromaSubsampling: "4:4:4",
      })
      .toFile(compressedImgPath)
      .then(() => {
        fsPromises.readFile(compressedImgPath)
          .then((result) => {
            const toInsertImgData = {
              data: result,
              contentType: "image/jpeg",
            };
            imgArray.push(toInsertImgData);
          })
          .then(() => {
            promises.push(fsPromises.unlink(compressedImgPath));
            promises.push(fsPromises.unlink(file.path));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      User.findById(id, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
          if (imgArray.length > 0) {
            console.log("found user:" + id);
            const newPost = new Post({
              uId: id,
              userName: result.name,
              timeStamp: "5th August, 2020 at 2:10PM",
              caption: caption,
              img: imgArray,
            });
            newPost.save((err) => {
              if (!err) {
                console.log("post saved in DB");
                res.redirect("/users/" + id.toString());
              } else {
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log("array is empty");
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

inside for each , you use async call, which means all .then() are guaranteed to be executed before .forEach end,so promises array can be ambiguous.
One easy fix is to use fs.promises inside.then() and not push it to promises.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very similar use case that might help solve the mentioned question. I have provided the full API route code to understand it better.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './public/uploads')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/imageupload', upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Image post request by " + req.user.username);

  await sharp('./public/uploads/' + req.file.filename).resize(150, 150)
    .rotate()
    .png({ quality: 100 }).toFile('./public/uploads/' + req.file.filename + '-thumb');

  Member.findOneAndUpdate({ sabhe_id: req.body.sabhe_id },
    {
      img: {
        data: fs.readFileSync(path.join('./public/uploads/' + req.file.filename + '-thumb')),
        contentType: 'image/png'
      }
    }
    , function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
      else {
        console.log("Image saved to database " + req.user.username);
        fs.unlink('./public/uploads/' + req.file.filename, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return
          }
        });
        fs.unlink('./public/uploads/' + req.file.filename + '-thumb', (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
            return
          }
        });
        if (req.user.isAdmin) {
          res.redirect("/admin")
        } else {
          res.redirect("/profile");
        }
      }
    }
  )
});
```